# how to use function(1)(2) in javascript? and how does it work?

Tags: javascript, function

I understand calling function(1) but not function(1)(2), how does it work?

also possible for function(1)(2)(3)(4) too?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In this case you are supposing that function(1) returns a function, than you are calling this new, anonymous function with an argument of 2.

See this example:

```
function sum(a) {
    return function(b) {
        return a+b;
    }
}

// Usage:
window.alert(sum(5)(3));         // shows 8

var add2 = sum(2);
window.alert(add2(5));           // shows 7
window.alert(typeof(add2));      // shows 'function'
```

Here we create a function `sum` that takes one argument. Inside the function `sum`, we create an `anonymous function` that takes another argument. This anonymous function is returned as the result of executing `sum`.

Note that this anonymous function is a great example of what we call **[closure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29)**. A closure is a function that keeps the context in which it was created. In this case, it will keep the value of the variable `a` inside it, as did the example function `add2`. If we create many closures, they are independent as you can see:

```
var add3 = sum(3);
var add4 = sum(4);

window.alert(add3(3)); // shows 6
window.alert(add4(3)); // shows 7
```

Furthermore, they won't get "confused" if you have similarly named local variables:

```
var a = "Hello, world";

function multiply(a) {
    return function(b) {
        return a * b;
    }
}

window.alert(multiply(6)(7)); // shows 42

var twoTimes = multiply(2);
window.alert(typeof(twoTimes));
window.alert(twoTimes(5));
```

So, after a call to `sum(2)` or `multiply(2)` the result is not a number, nor a string, but is a `function`. This is a characteristic of *[functional languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming)* -- languages in which functions can be passed as parameters and returned as results of other functions.

Answer (score 4):

You have a function that returns a function:

```
function f(n) {
  return function(x) {
    return n + x;
  };
}
```

When you call f(1) you get a reference to a function back. You can either store the reference in a variable and call it:

```
var fx = f(1);
var result = fx(2);
```

Or you can call it directly:

```
var result = f(1)(2);
```

To get a function that returns a function that returns a function that returns a function, you just have to repeat the process:

```
function f(n) {
  return function(x) {
    return function(y) {
      return function(z) {
        return n + x + y + z;
      }
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: Curious about the downvote? If you don't explain what it is that you don't like, it's rather pointless...

Answer (score 1):

If your function returns a function, you can call that too.

```
x = f(1)(2)
```

is equivalent to:

```
f2 = f(1)
x = f2(2)
```

Answer (score 1):

The parenthesis indicate invocation of a function (you "call" it). If you have

```
<anything>()
```

It means that the value of `anything` is a callable value. Imagine the following function:

```
function add(n1) {
    return function add_second(n2) { 
        return n1+n2
    }
}
```

You can then invoke it as `add(1)(2)` which would equal 3. You can naturally extend this as much as you want.

Comment: No need to give a name to the function being returned, btw. `return function(n2)` would be just as good, and less typing, too.

Comment: I know. I felt maybe it would be better to not muddy the issue at hand by also using anonymous functions.