# "int -> int -> int" What does this mean in F#?

Tags: f#, functional-programming, currying

I wonder what this means in F#.
**“a function taking an integer, 
which returns a function which takes an integer and returns an integer.”**
But I don't understand this well.
Can anyone explain this so clear ?

[Update]:

```
> let f1 x y = x+y ;;

 val f1 : int -> int -> int
```

What this mean ?

Comment: Your new snippet is just a simple function that takes 2 int values and return a new int value which is the sum.

So f1 5 4 will equal 9.

The part "val f1 : int -> int -> int" is just F# telling you the result of the function you just declared on the previous line.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/104618/what-does-mean-in-f

Answer (score 58, accepted):

## F# types

Let's begin from the beginning.

F# uses the colon (`:`) notation to indicate types of things. Let's say you define a value of type `int`:

```
let myNumber = 5
```

F# Interactive will understand that `myNumber` is an integer, and will tell you this by:

```
myNumber : int
```

which is read as

> `myNumber` is of type `int`

## F# functional types

So far so good. Let's introduce something else, **functional types**. A functional type is simply the *type of a function*. F# uses `->` to denote a functional type. This arrow symbolizes that what is written on its left-hand side is transformed into what is written into its right-hand side.

Let's consider a simple function, that takes one argument and transforms it into one output. An example of such a function would be:

```
isEven : int -> bool
```

This introduces the name of the function (on the left of the `:`), and its type. This line can be read in English as:

> `isEven` is of type function that transforms an `int` into a `bool`.

Note that to correctly interpret what is being said, you should make a short pause just after the part "is of type", and then read the rest of the sentence at once, without pausing.

## In F# functions are values

In F#, functions are (almost) no more special than *ordinary* types. They are things that you can pass around to functions, return from functions, just like bools, ints or strings.

So if you have:

```
myNumber : int
isEven : int -> bool
```

You should consider `int` and `int -> bool` as two entities of the same kind: types. Here, `myNumber` is a value of type `int`, and `isEven` is a value of type `int -> bool` (this is what I'm trying to symbolize when I talk about the *short pause* above).

## Function application

Values of types that contain `->` happens to be also called *functions*, and have special powers: you can *apply* a function to a value. So, for example,

```
isEven myNumber
```

means that you are applying the function called `isEven` to the value `myNumber`. As you can expect by inspecting the type of `isEven`, it will return a boolean value. If you have correctly implemented `isEven`, it would obviously return `false`.

## A function that returns a value of a functional type

Let's define a generic function to determine is an integer is multiple of some other integer. We can imagine that our function's type will be (the parenthesis are here to help you understand, they might or might not be present, they have a special meaning):

```
isMultipleOf : int -> (int -> bool)
```

As you can guess, this is read as:

> `isMultipleOf` is of type (PAUSE) function that transforms an `int` into (PAUSE) function that transforms an `int` into a `bool`.

(here the (PAUSE) denote the pauses when reading out loud).

We will define this function later. Before that, let's see how we can use it:

```
let isEven = isMultipleOf 2
```

F# interactive would answer:

```
isEven : int -> bool
```

which is read as

> `isEven` is of type `int -> bool`

Here, `isEven` has type `int -> bool`, since we have just given the value 2 (`int`) to `isMultipleOf`, which, as we have already seen, transforms an `int` into an `int -> bool`.

We can view this function `isMultipleOf` as a sort of *function creator*.

### Definition of `isMultipleOf`

So now let's define this mystical function-creating function.

```
let isMultipleOf n x =
    (x % n) = 0
```

Easy, huh?

If you type this into F# Interactive, it will answer:

```
isMultipleOf : int -> int -> bool
```

#### Where are the parenthesis?

Note that there are no parenthesis. This is not particularly important for you now. Just remember that the arrows are *right associative*. That is, if you have

```
a -> b -> c
```

you should interpret it as

```
a -> (b -> c)
```

The *right* in *right associative* means that you should interpret as if there were parenthesis around the rightmost operator. So:

```
a -> b -> c -> d
```

should be interpreted as

```
a -> (b -> (c -> d))
```

### Usages of `isMultipleOf`

So, as you have seen, we can use `isMultipleOf` to create new functions:

```
let isEven = isMultipleOf 2
let isOdd = not << isEven
let isMultipleOfThree = isMultipleOf 3
let endsWithZero = isMultipleOf 10
```

F# Interactive would respond:

```
isEven : int -> bool
isOdd : int -> bool
isMultipleOfThree : int -> bool
endsWithZero : int -> bool
```

But you can use it differently. If you don't want to (or need to) create a new function, you can use it as follows:

```
isMultipleOf 10 150
```

This would return `true`, as 150 is multiple of 10. This is exactly the same as create the function `endsWithZero` and then applying it to the value 150.

Actually, **function application is left associative**, which means that the line above should be interpreted as:

```
(isMultipleOf 10) 150
```

That is, you put the parenthesis around the leftmost function application.

Now, if you can understand all this, your example (which is the canonical `CreateAdder`) should be trivial!

Sometime ago someone asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1775309/how-to-use-function12-in-javascript-and-how-does-it-work) which deals with exactly the same concept, but in Javascript. In my answer I give two canonical examples (CreateAdder, CreateMultiplier) inf Javascript, that are somewhat more explicit about returning functions.

I hope this helps.

Comment: That's a really helpful, in-depth answer!!

Comment: Man you write a chapter here When complete book is out ;)

Comment: This is the best explaination on the topic of functional types that I've read so far.

Comment: I think there is an error in the "Usages of isMultipleOf".  Shouldn't isOdd be: not << isEven

Comment: @YotaXP, yes, you are absolutely right. Thanks for the remark, I've fixed that error!

Comment: Hot dog, that's a complete answer. +1

Comment: It all makes sense now. Bruno, have my children por favor!

Answer (score 9):

The canonical example of this is probably an "adder creator" - a function which, given a number (e.g. 3) returns another function which takes an integer and adds the first number to it.

So, for example, in pseudo-code

```
x = CreateAdder(3)
x(5) // returns 8
x(10) // returns 13
CreateAdder(20)(30) // returns 50
```

I'm not quite comfortable enough in F# to try to write it without checking it, but the C# would be something like:

```
public static Func<int, int> CreateAdder(int amountToAdd)
{
    return x => x + amountToAdd;
}
```

Does that help?

EDIT: As Bruno noted, the example you've given in your question is exactly the example I've given C# code for, so the above pseudocode would become:

```
let x = f1 3
x 5 // Result: 8
x 10 // Result: 13
f1 20 30 // Result: 50
```

Comment: I Updated my question so can you explane the snippet ?

Comment: Jon, the F# version is exactly what the OP called `f1` in his question. To use it: `let x = f1 3`, `x 5`, `x 10`, `f1 20 30`, following your examples.

Comment: Does this mean F# converts my f1 function to another one which just takes one parameter ?

Comment: @ali62b: Basically yes. If you think about functions as values (the fundamental thing in a functional language) this makes sense. Assume the return value of `f1` function with one argument is simply another function (a delegate in C# way of doing things).

Comment: @ali62b: I'm not sure whether I'd say it's "converting" it - that's just what your function declaration means. But if it's simpler to understand as a conversion, that probably won't do you any harm.

Comment: Thanks Mehrdad & Jon your answers was really helpful +1

Comment: The most important thing in functional programming is to think of values and functions as the same thing. For example, you can think of the literal `10` as a function that takes no arguments and returns an integer. Conversley, you can think of the exponential function `exp`, for example, as a value. A function that takes more than one argument can be thought of similarly: you can pass it one argument and it'll return a function that takes the remaining arguments, or you can pass it all its arguments, and it'll return the result. This is all possible because of functional purity.

Comment: @Zakalwe, actually it has nothing to do with pure functions. You can have any side-effects you might want in such functions.

Comment: Of course, in a curried language like F#, we could simply define `create_adder` as `create_adder = (+)`.

Answer (score 7):

It's a function that takes an integer and returns a function that takes an integer and returns an integer.

This is functionally equivalent to a function that takes two integers and returns an integer. This way of treating functions that take multiple parameters is common in functional languages and makes it easy to *partially apply* a function on a value.

For example, assume there's an add function that takes two integers and adds them together:

```
let add x y = x + y
```

You have a list and you want to add 10 to each item. You'd partially apply `add` function to the value `10`. It would bind one of the parameters to 10 and leaves the other argument unbound.

```
let list = [1;2;3;4]
let listPlusTen = List.map (add 10)
```

This trick makes composing functions very easy and makes them very reusable. As you can see, you don't need to write another function that adds 10 to the list items to pass it to `map`. You have just reused the `add` function.

Comment: > let f1 x y = x+y ;;

val f1 : int -> int -> int

I'm confused what this mean ?

Comment: I Updated my question so can you explane the snippet ?

Comment: @ali62b: In F#, functions don't use parentheses to declare their parameters. Basically, f(int x, int y) in C# becomes `let f x y = ...`

Comment: your comment is not entirely true. You can (and sometimes need to) declare functions taking tuples.

Comment: @Bruno: In the case of tuples, the parentheses are for the "tuple declaration", not parameter declaration. `let f (x,y)` takes a *single* argument of a tuple *type*.

Answer (score 6):

You usually interpret this as a function that takes two integers and returns an integer.
You should read about [currying](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying).

Answer (score 2):

> a function taking an integer, which returns a function which takes an integer and returns an integer

The last part of that:

> a function which takes an integer and returns an integer

should be rather simple, C# example:

```
public int Test(int takesAnInteger) { return 0; }
```

So we're left with

> a function taking an integer, which returns *(a function like the one above)*

C# again:

```
public int Test(int takesAnInteger) { return 0; }
public int Test2(int takesAnInteger) { return 1; }

public Func<int,int> Test(int takesAnInteger) {
    if(takesAnInteger == 0) {
        return Test;
    } else {
        return Test2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to read

[F# function types: fun with tuples and currying](http://lorgonblog.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!701679AD17B6D310!169.entry)

Answer (score 1):

In F# (and many other functional languages), there's a concept called curried functions. This is what you're seeing. Essentially, every function takes one argument and returns one value.

This seems a bit confusing at first, because you can write `let add x y = x + y` and it appears to add two arguments. But actually, the original `add` function only takes the argument `x`. When you apply it, it returns a function that takes one argument (`y`) and has the `x` value already filled in. When you then apply that function, it returns the desired integer.

This is shown in the type signature. Think of the arrow in a type signature as meaning "takes the thing on my left side and returns the thing on my right side". In the type `int -> int -> int`, this means that it takes an argument of type `int` — an integer — and returns a function of type `int -> int` — a function that takes an integer and returns an integer. You'll notice that this precisely matches the description of how curried functions work above.

Answer (score 0):

Example:

`let f b a = pown a b //f a b = a^b`

is a function that takes an int (the exponent) and returns a function that raises its argument to that exponent, like

`let sqr = f 2`

or

`let tothepowerofthree = f 3`

so

`sqr 5 = 25`

`tothepowerofthree 3 = 27`

Answer (score 0):

The concept is called [Higher Order Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher_order_functions) and quite common to functional programming.

Functions themselves are just another type of data. Hence you can write functions that return other functions. Of course you can still have a function that takes an int as parameter and returns something else. Combine the two and consider the following example (in python):

```
def mult_by(a):
    def _mult_by(x):
        return x*a
    return mult_by

mult_by_3 = mult_by(3)

print mylt_by_3(3)
9
```

(sorry for using python, but i don't know f#)

Comment: Is python also functional language ?

Comment: not per se, but you can do a good deal of functional programming with it.

Answer (score 0):

*There are already lots of answers here, but I'd like to offer another take. Sometimes explaining the same thing in lots of different ways helps you to 'grok' it.*

I like to think of functions as "you give me something, and I'll give you something else back"

So a `Func<int, string>` says "you give me an int, and I'll give you a string".

I also find it easier to think in terms of 'later' : "*When* you give me an int, I'll give you a string". This is especially important when you see things like `myfunc = x => y => x + y` ("*When* you give curried an x, you get back something which *when* you give it a y will return x + y").

(By the way, I'm assuming you're familiar with C# here)

So we could express your  `int -> int -> int` example as `Func<int, Func<int, int>>`.

Another way that I look at  `int -> int -> int` is that you peel away each element from the left by providing an argument of the appropriate type. And when you have no more `->`'s, you're out of 'laters' and you get a value.

---

(Just for fun), you can transform a function which takes all it's arguments in one go into one which takes them 'progressively' (the official term for applying them progressively is 'partial application'), this is called 'currying':

```
static void Main()
{
    //define a simple add function
    Func<int, int, int> add = (a, b) => a + b;

    //curry so we can apply one parameter at a time
    var curried = Curry(add);    

    //'build' an incrementer out of our add function
    var inc = curried(1);         // (var inc = Curry(add)(1) works here too)
    Console.WriteLine(inc(5));    // returns 6
    Console.ReadKey();
}
static Func<T, Func<T, T>> Curry<T>(Func<T, T, T> f)
{
    return a => b => f(a, b);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my 2 c. By default F# functions enable partial application or currying. This means when you define this:

```
let adder a b = a + b;;
```

You are defining a function that **takes and integer and returns a function that takes an integer and returns an integer** or `int -> int -> int`. Currying then allows you partiallly apply a function to create another function:

```
let twoadder = adder 2;;
//val it: int -> int
```

The above code predifined a to 2, so that whenever you call `twoadder 3` it will simply add two to the argument.

The syntax where the function parameters are separated by space is equivalent to this lambda syntax:

```
let adder = fun a -> fun b -> a + b;;
```

Which is a more readable way to figure out that the two functions are actually chained.